# Random forest feature importance vs. feature correlation to PCA eigenvectors

Tags: pca, feature-selection, random-forest, bioinformatics

I have recently built a random forest model for classifying two types of cancer based on patients' genetic profile. I used patients' genetic markers (SNPs) as my features and disease status as my outcome.

My question however is why top ranked features in my model are not the same as the features with high correlation to PCA eigenvectors? It seems like they are completely different features?

If both techniques try to put more weight on features that describe  greatest amount of variability within data why they are discordant?

P.S: following discussion below I am enclosing my PCA plot. You can see a nice pattern of clustering/separation between the two groups and this is why I expected top ranked features in RF classifier be the same as highly correlated features to PCA eigenvectors!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Presumably you do PCA on SNPs without taking cancer type into account, whereas random forest aims to predict cancer type. Why do you expect them to select same features?

Comment: In the PCA plot, I see a nice pattern of clustering/separation between the two groups and this is why I expected top ranked features in RF classifier be the same as highly correlated features to PCA eigenvectors!

Comment: OK, this is important information, you might want to edit your question to add it. It might be helpful to post your PCA plot and your random forest feature ranking (top of the list) together with the corresponding PCA eigenvector values.

Comment: Re first plot: I actually don't see separation between the two groups (red/black). I see two clusters, but they don't seem to correspond to the groups. Re second plot: I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? If you wanted to model the same data, what would be your approach?